# Recording / Logging CSP Violations

Tags: domains, security, http-headers, logging, headers

I am in the process of implementing a CSP policy for a variety of domains and am looking for a method to record/log browser CSP violations encountered by any end user. I want to make sure I don't miss any domains, but would like to avoid having to manually visit every page and check the browser error console. What's the best practice here to identify external domains and resources that may be encountered?

Answer (score 1):

**Content Security Policy (CSP)**
[Quick Reference Guide](https://content-security-policy.com)

**CSP-Reporting** on [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#reporting)

> If you're just starting out with CSP, it makes sense to evaluate the
> current state of your application before rolling out a draconian
> policy to your users. As a stepping stone to a complete deployment,
> you can ask the browser to monitor a policy, reporting violations but
> not enforcing the restrictions. Instead of sending a
> *Content-Security-Policy* header, send a ***Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only*** header.

1. **The Reporting API** on [google.dev](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/reportingapi)
2. **Reporting API** on [github.io (Editor's Draft)](https://w3c.github.io/reporting/)
3. **Report URI** [Documentation](https://docs.report-uri.com) - probably the easiest and fastest way to deploy policies and generate reports to track CSP violations. Includes [CSP Analyser](https://report-uri.com/home/analyse/), [CSP Builder](https://report-uri.com/home/generate/) and Data Watch monitoring tool for registered users. However, the free plan includes up to 10,000 reports.